# MariaDB issue I cannot seem to figure out

Tags: mariadb

ALTER TABLE items Add 'limit' INT(5);
/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''limit' INT(5)' at line 1 /

Comment: If you want to use a keyword as a column (such as limit), use back ticks with the column name, not single quotes. See [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/23130).

Comment: BTW, the `(5)` means nothing.  Perhaps you want `SMALLINT`?